Making small talk: Which verbs most commonly accept “small talk” as their direct object?
I know that you can use make because you can say (to) make small talk.
But is it also acceptable and reasonably common to say either of these two?

(to) hold small talk (meaning to hold a conversation)
(to) have small talk (meaning to have a conversation)

What are the most natural and accepted collocations here?

@Greybeard I think it's a valid question, because the OP also asks about the acceptability of specific verbs (hold and have).

@Greybeard No, despite the original wording of this question about collocations, I don't think that's what Kevin is really asking about here. I think he simply wants to know whether you ever use other verbs beyond make in making small talk, so synonyms thereof. I don't believe he's truly looking for all the random verbal collocates that routinely pair up with this compound noun, which would indeed be rather broad for a question. I think what he's "actually" looking for is not too broad of a question for us, but this may not be clear in the wording. I tried to edit it to improve that.

You can also engage in small talk or be engaged in small talk
(in addition to make/hold/have small talk)

engage in
Be a participant in, a party to.
If you engage in local politics, you cannot expect to have much time for your family.
engaged in (pass.)
(Be) busy doing sth, occupied with.
'Those men are behaving very suspiciously. They're engaged in some fishy business, I'll be bound.'
A.P. Cowie and R. Mackin, eds.; Oxford Dictionary of Current Idiomatic English. Vol. 1: Verbs with Prepositions & Particles (1975)


engage in phrasal verb
To do (something)
At college she engaged in various sports.
We don't engage in that sort of behavior.
M-W


engage in
Phrasal verb with engage verb
To take part in something:
The two governments have agreed to engage in a comprehensive dialogue to resolve the problem.
Cambridge



Does she want to make "small talk" while she reacclimates to being
here again?
...
For example, if the client is engaged in "small
talk" about what happened during the week as a way to warm up to more
important concerns, .bu I hear this a giving me background material
for responding to some difficulty, we are at cross-purposes.
David A
Pare and ‎Glen Larner; Collaborative Practice in Psychology and
Therapy (2014)


Once engaged in small talk, maintain appropriate eye contact and
face the person you're attracted to.
Melissa Wadsworth; Small Talk
Savvy (2011)


Chapter 7: Getting to Know You: Making Small Talk
...
Whatever the case, the ability to engage in small talk is important.
You need to be aware of a number of rules when you make small talk
in Arabic.
Amine Bouchentouf; Arabic for Dummies (2013)


Just like learning any new skill, the more you engage in small
talk, the more natural it will become.
Esther Reid; Small Talk,
Big Impact: The Art of Effortless Chat  (2024)


They made small talk for some minutes, shifting over to the side
of the corridor to allow other guests access to the bar.
Celina
Grace; Creed (2015)

Melissa Wadsworth; How to Make Small Talk (2017)

"I have my looks. I have a certain grace. I know which fork to hold,
small talk to make. I know an Italian wine from a French. A Monet from a Manet. The rest I can fudge if need be."
David Baldacci; The
Forgotten. (2012)

I would have thought that hold small talk was much less common, but I would be wrong:

Back then there was no Azra and no me with a calm enough head to
hold small talk with the check in agents.
Akosua Dardaine Edwards; Now What (2021)


Moreover, it was certainly helpful to understand at least something of
what was said during interviews, and being able to hold 'small
talk', so that the natural distance which a language barrier builds
could be somewhat impaired.
Nadine Reis; Tracing and Making the
State (2012)


"Don't tell me I've said things I didn't say. Especially about persons
who you are ill-equipped to hold small talk with, let alone
discuss their relative cerebral merit, Nurse Lewis."
Stacey Abrams;
While Justice Sleeps (2022)

In Google Books you can find similar examples for have small talk.
An Ngram shows that make small talk appears to be most common of these choices.

Secret smalltalk skills underpin our modern world. :)

@tchrist Another well-programmed comment!!

I feel like when the asker asked for small talk collocations, they were asking overly broadly and not asking what they really meant to ask. This I observe because, depending mainly on which dolven corpora one selects, countless potential collocations exist — provided one disregard relative frequency: make, do, hold, enjoy, observe, exchange, offer, stop, hate, avoid, ignore; engage in, flit across, stumble over.  There’s also the minor matter of how this compound noun can and does occur in all three of the normal variations for such; namely small talk, small-talk, smalltalk.

Is "small talk" actually a direct object in "engage in small talk"?

This is not overly broad if you use some common sense about the question. We are getting overly technical about what’s acceptable and what’s not. The rules are not an end in themselves—unless the goal is to drive questions to zero and thus close the site.

@Xanne You're spot on the money here. The close-voters have forgotten the Principle of Charity.

@tchrist: By the "Principle of Charity" I think youi shouldn't have deleted my comment explaining my cosevote, and linking to many published examples of a verb I've now forgotten which could have figured in the (effectively, open-ended) list of verbs that can be used in reference to making / engaging in / holding / exchanging / having small talk.

+1, but the quotation with "engage in small talk behaviors" and the one with "hold small talk conversations" are misleading; those are examples of "engage in X behaviors" and "hold X conversations", respectively, where X just happens to be "small talk".

@ruakh I see your point. I've replaced both with other examples. Thanks

@tchrist I've added be engaged in, which is a distinct construction.

@user2357112 Yes, the phrasal verb (engage in) takes objects. I've added definitions. –

You can exchange small talk, as well as make small talk. Or you can say something like “Talking about the weather is just small talk.” This is a good use of Google Ngram:
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*_VERB+small+talk&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3
No other verbs show up.

Not in books maybe, but I get lots of ghits for "teach" and "learn".
